# changing price in mini-cart for woocommerce change after a second to previous one

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I am using the code below to calculate the prices for some specific products in certain categories and it works. the cart shows the corret value just like the checkout. The problem is in the mini-cart (if that is the correct name for the cart panel that shows up whenever i add a product in the cart.) I can see the correct price with the correct suffix that i have added and then the price returns back to its original.
however in the cart page and the checkout page they are calculating the right way and it seems to work fine. Thank you for your help

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'sv_change_product_price_cart', 10, 1 );
function sv_change_product_price_cart( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        

        $product = $cart_item['data'];  
        //check if is simple product
        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) )
        {
            //check if is desired category
            if ( has_term( array( 'tiles', 'tiles2' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
                $product_id = $product->get_id(); 
                $ppbox = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'ppbox', true );
                $product_price = $product->get_price();
                $new_price=$ppbox*$product_price;
                //$cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price );
            
                // WooCommerce versions compatibility
                if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) {
                    $cart_item['data']->price = $new_price; // Before WC 3.0
                } else {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price ); // WC 3.0+
                }
            }   
        }
        else
        { //if product has variations
            //find parent id and use it to find parent category 
            $parent_id = $product->get_parent_id(); // The parent product ID
            if ( has_term( array( 'tiles', 'tiles2' ), 'product_cat', $parent_id ) ) {
                $ppbox = get_post_meta( $parent_id, 'ppbox', true ); //using parent id we find ppbox value
                $product_price = $product->get_price();
                $new_price=$ppbox*$product_price;
                if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) {
                  $cart_item['data']->price = $new_price; // Before WC 3.0
                } else {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price ); // WC 3.0+
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Changing the displayed price (with custom label)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'sv_display_product_price_cart', 100, 3 );
function sv_display_product_price_cart( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
        
        
        $product = $cart_item['data'];  
        //check if is simple product
        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) )
        {
            //check if is desired category
            if ( has_term( array( 'tiles', 'tiles2' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            
                return wc_price($product->get_price())."/box";
            }   
        }
        else
        { //if product has variations
            //find parent id and use it to find parent category 
            //$product = $cart_item->get_product();
            $parent_id = $product->get_parent_id(); // The parent product ID
            if ( has_term( array( 'tiles', 'tiles2' ), 'product_cat', $parent_id ) ) {
                
                return wc_price($product->get_price())."/box";
            }
        }
        return wc_price($product->get_price());
}
```

Comment: To admin or whoever closed the question: I dont understand why my question is closed. since is not the same problem with the others. the code works for everything but for mini cart where it has an issue. thanks again

Comment: You need to check the modified data of the cart item. Replace `return wc_price($product->get_price());` with `if ( $new_price = $cart_item['data']->get_changes()['price'] ) { return wc_price( $new_price ); } else { return wc_price( $product->get_price() ); }`. It will work.

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano thanks for your reply, but its not working. $new_price is not even declared in function sv_display_product_price_cart. Please correct me if i am wrong or i misunderstood you. thanks again

Comment: It is declared and valued directly within the if statement. It works, test it. Note that this is not an equality.

Comment: You can optimize it further like this: `if ( isset($cart_item['data']->get_changes()['price']) && $new_price = $cart_item['data']->get_changes()['price'] ) { return wc_price( $new_price ); } else { return wc_price( $product->get_price() ); }`

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano Hello again, unfortunately your code was not working in my case i dont know the reason however i managed to make it work by removing the "sv_display_product_price_cart" filter when calling "sv_change_product_price_cart" function 
and adding a new function for example "add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'add_label', 100, 3 )" 
where i just add suffix to $product->get_price()."box" . 

Thanks for your help cause it somehow make me think about the price change and the sequense of functions.